# Cirqus - Rollbacking Events

Tags: transactions, event-handling, cirqus

we are using Cirqus as an event repository (in SQL Server) but our views are hand-crafted (handling the dispatched event via a custom IEventDispatcher) in RavenDb.

Problem comes when for some reason one of the handlers for the dispatched event fails. In that situation the event has been commited to the store, but the "views" are not in sync with what in the event store. In our case, that becomes a problem.

What would be the best way to approach this situation and "get rid of" the mismatch?
Note: enlisting the whole operation inside a distributed transaction (via TransactionScope) is not a possibility.

We are using 0.41.0 and we'd like to avoid updating if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I like that you say that you do not want to enlist everything in a transaction - both because it's not readily possible to do that, but mostly because I don't think it makes sense.

As I see it, the domain should not depend on any of the views' ability to catch up. I think you should of course be very careful to write the views so that they cannot fail, but in case one of the views *should* fail, the best thing it can do is to log it as an error (or communicate otherwise that it has failed) and stop processing events.

The way this is handled with Cirqus' out-of-the-box view managers (those hosted by the `ViewManagerEventDispatcher`) is simply by stopping event processing in the event of a failure. And then, if the failure is transient, the views will automatically resume processing events when the failure is over.

This way, the views will never miss processing any events. But you should probably be careful to write your views so that they're very unlikely to fail.